# Preserve data written to DOM object after cloneNode()

Tags: javascript, dom

At the moment when I write a (complex) value to a dom node object the value is lost when I perform a cloneNode on the node, see example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ohGDy

Is there a way of preserving this data with cloneNode()?

Keep in mind that both the node being cloned as well as the value being set may be far more complex than the example (ie. the value may be set on a sub-node of the node being cloned and may be an object rather than a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloneNode copies an htmlDomObject, an htmlDomObject has html attributes it does not have properties like a normal javascript object. Javascript being javascript it will allow you to assign a property to a domObject because it will let you do whatever you want.

However cloneNode specifically deals with domObjects and a domObject cannot have a string property, which if you do `typeof foo.bar` you will see that it is indeed a typeof string.

I changed your code to this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.setAttribute('bar', 'foobar');
var foo2 = foo.cloneNode(true);
document.write("foo: " + foo.getAttribute('bar') + "<br>");
document.write("foo2: " + foo2.getAttribute('bar'));
```

And for both it prints out `foobar`, so you can see that an ***html*** attribute set on the node is copied by cloneNode.

edited codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ltiov

Comment: Right, and that works fine for simple values but not complex values. Unless you'd want to start encoding/decoding values. What I'm essentially wondering is if there is a way to write custom properties to a html dom object.

Comment: @Naatan not with standard html. But there are ways to work around that, that's pretty much what angular and ember do. They associate complex values (the models) with dom elements.